# can't open file app. Kubernetes and Docker

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes

I get the error: ***python: can't open file 'app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory*** when I try to create a deployment. I have included the folder structure, deployment and PVC manifests.

When I create a container from the docker image which I built using the docker file below, it runs fine - STATUS: Running.

I suspect it might have something to do with the persistent volumes or the way I have written my paths. I have tried the long-form (/var/www/code/order_service/app..) for my paths as well but face the same issue.

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance guys.

Docker File

```
FROM python:3-alpine3.10


COPY ./app/requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --update \
     bash \
     curl \
     py-mysqldb \
     gcc \
     libc-dev \
     mariadb-dev \
     nodejs \
     npm \
  && pip install --upgrade pip  \
  && pip install -r requirements.txt \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY ./app/package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install

COPY ./app /app

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Folder structure

```
code
  order_service
    app
     app.py
```

Here is my manifest:

```
DEPLOYMENT

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: order
  name: order
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: order
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: order
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: order:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: order
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: ./app
          name: order-claim0
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: order-claim0
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: order-claim0
status: {}


PVC

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: order-claim0
  name: order-claim0
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}
```

Comment: Try to run `sh` in a container based on the image and see if the file exists and the workdir is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't get the point.

In `Dockerfile`, you put `app.py` in docker image's folder `/app`

```
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./app /app

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Then in Kubernetes, you try to replace the folder `/app` with a persistent volume.

But how the first one comes from?

```
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: ./app
          name: order-claim0
```

So that's the reason, when you run locally with that docker image, it is fine, but when you run a similar command as below, it will be failed.

```
docker run -ti --rm -v $(New_Local_folder_somewhere):/app order:1.0
```

Because the folder `/app` has been replaced with a totally new mounted folder.

Second, could you use absolute path more than relative path in this case?

```
        - mountPath: ./app

change to 

        - mountPath: /app
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. It makes sense now. Sorry, I was following a course and I guess there was an error there.

What are we trying to achieve with this recommendation?------>>>>

Second, could you use absolute path more than relative path in this case?

        - mountPath: ./app

change to 

        - mountPath: /app

Comment: You should vote the answer, then put the comments to thank. :-)

Comment: Voted. Thanks, BMW. Can you help explain the question?----->>>>What are we trying to achieve with this recommendation?------>>>> Second, could you use absolute path more than relative path in this case? - mountPath: ./app change to - mountPath: /app

Comment: read this to understand absolute path and related path: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/